# Detecting whether a method/function exists in Java

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a method/function in Java that checks if another method/function is available just like `function_exists(functionName)` in PHP?

Here I am referring to a method/function of static class.

Comment: What do you mean by "static class"? Only nested classes are declared as "static" in Java, and that's not really the same thing...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You *can* find out if a method exists in Java using reflection.

Get the [`Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object of the class you're interested in and call [`getMethod()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) with the method name and parameter types on it.

If the method doesn't exist, it will throw a [`NoSuchMethodException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodException.html).

Also, please note that "functions" are called methods in Java.

Last but not least: keep in mind that *if you think you need this*, then chances are that you've got a design problem at hand. Reflection (which is what the methods to inspect the actual Java classes is called) is a rather specialized feature of Java and should *not* generally be used in business code (although it's used quite heavily and to some nice effects in some common libraries).

Comment: I need to make it backward compatible. I have a METHOD [:)] which is added to the library and I need to check if that method exists. Not all system has been updated with that library.

Comment: [`Class.getMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) will only work if the method is `public`. Otherwise you will probably want to use [`Class.getDeclaredMethods`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods%28%29) per @JonSkeet answer.

Comment: @Windle: that's true, but the use case in the question (checking if a method in a library exists) *most likely* involves a public method.

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer because relying on exceptions to guide the execution of your code is slow and considered bad practice.

Answer (score 11):

I *suspect* you're looking for [`Class.getDeclaredMethods`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods%28%29) and [`Class.getMethods`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29) which will give you the methods of a class. You can then test whether the one you're looking for exists or not, and what it's parameters are etc.

Answer (score 9):

You can use Reflections to lookup if the method exists:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Class clazz = Test.class;

        for (Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                if (method.getName().equals("fooBar")) {
                System.out.println("Method fooBar exists.");
            }
        }

        if (clazz.getDeclaredMethod("fooBar", null) != null) {
            System.out.println("Method fooBar exists.");
        }
   }

   private static void fooBar() {
   }
  }
```

But Reflection is not really fast so be careful when to use it (probably cache it).

Answer (score 5):

Try using the [`Class.getMethod()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) method of the Class class =)

```
public class Foo {
  public static String foo(Integer x) {
    // ...
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Method fooMethod = Foo.class.getMethod("foo", Integer.class);
    System.out.println(fooMethod);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks maerics. This is exactly what I wanted... :)

Answer (score 3):

Here my solution using reflection...

```
    public static boolean methodExists(Class clazz, String methodName) {
    boolean result = false;
    for (Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (method.getName().equals(methodName)) {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Great solution, one comment: Break the loop after result = true to avoid unnecessary checks after method is found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reflection API to achieve this.

```
YourStaticClass.getClass().getMethods();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like this

```
Obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(MethodName, parameterTypes)
```